# Why are these nested SQL Server transactions throwing a mismatch error if there is a rollback?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, nested, rollback

By running 'Test Errors' I get unexpected results. I thought by checking for `@@Trancount` it would avoid mismatches. Can anyone help me with a better way to rollback errors? I want to rollback all transactions which are nested. Stored procedures can be both nested and on their own.

```
alter procedure TestErrors
as
begin
    begin try
        begin transaction

        exec TestErrorsInner;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            commit transaction;
    end try
    begin catch
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            rollback transaction;
        select ERROR_MESSAGE();
    end catch
end

alter procedure TestErrorsInner
as
begin
    begin try
        begin transaction

        RAISERROR('Test Error',16,1);

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            commit transaction;
    end try
    begin catch
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            rollback transaction;
        select ERROR_MESSAGE();
    end catch
end
```

Results:

> Test Error
>
> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

Comment: See: [SQL Server DBA myth a day - nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are catching a transaction in the TestErrors which is not in Active state.

You have already rolled back your transaction in `Catch` block of `TestErrorsInner`.
Then again you are trying to do **COMMIT/ROLLBACK** it in `TestErrors`. So it is throwing an error.

It is your responsibility to Raise an Error explicitly again in `Catch` block of `TestErrorsInner`. So that Error will be the input for Parent SP.

So your `TestErrorsInner` should be like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TESTERRORSINNER
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        RAISERROR('TEST ERROR',16,1);

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        --SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();
         RAISERROR('TEST ERROR in Catch',16,1);  --Here Raised 
    END CATCH
END
```

Now execute the `TestErrors` Stored procedure, you won't get that error.

And You can check the Transaction Status with `XACT_STATE()`

Calling `XACT_STATE()` will give result of 0 or 1 or -1  (From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx))

- If 1, the transaction is committable.
- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should  be rolled back.
- if XACT_STATE = 0 means there is no transaction and   a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.

Comment: Because SP's may be called directly or nested within another SP, How should I do it so that the outer SP doesn't have a RAISERROR in the catch block?

Comment: IF @@TRANCOUNT > 1 RAISERROR..; IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION?